# How to use .env File with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I have a Jenkins Pipeline to run my test suite in Cypress, in the cypress project i use a .env file to store sensible data like user credentials to execute the tests.

How can i set the process.env on Jenkins to use in my cypress project?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your credentials in a [Jenkins credentials store](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#adding-new-global-credentials). Then you can use these credentials within the pipeline like below.

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh '''
      curl -H "Token: $TOKEN" https://some.api/
    '''
}
```

If you want to add them to a .env file you can add them to a file like below.

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh '''
      echo "mytoken=$TOKEN" >> process.env
    '''
}
```